# How to capture only 5minutes video with Xamarin.Essentials MediaPicker in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, video-capture, xamarin.essentials

We are creating Capture Images & Videos with Xamarin Essentials MediaPicker in xamarin forms.

```
await Xamarin.Essentials.MediaPicker.CaptureVideoAsync();
```

Video capturing more than 10 minutes long. How to restrict only capture 5minutes video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Xamarin Essentials MediaPicker** is still in preview and doesn't support such an option until now .

We could use the plugin [Media.Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) from nuget .

#### Usage

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
                return;
            }


            // record video
            //var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakeVideoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreVideoOptions
            //{
            //    DesiredLength = new TimeSpan(300),  //set length here 300s
            //    Quality = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.VideoQuality.High
            //});

            //if (file == null)
            //    return;

            //take photo
            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
            {
                Directory = "Sample",
                Name = "test.jpg"
            });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

            image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                return stream;
            });
        }
```